# Missing environment variable (PATH) when calling batch from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am currently troubleshooting an unattended installation of a special software. I narrowed down the problem onto a missing environment variable and I am very confused now because I don't know why it is missing.

I can reproduce the issue like this:

I have a batch file called `batch.cmd`. This file contains the following code:

```
SET
Pause
```

The `SET` command lists the environment variables.

I call this script from PowerShell like:

```
$Status = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\...\Batch.cmd" -PassThru -Wait
```

I did also try to call it like:

```
& C:\...\Batch.cmd
```

As result I am missing 2 folder paths in **PATH** variable compared to running the batch script directly. Have a look at the screenshot:

[image: Output-Comparison]

As you see the **PATH** variable contains more entries if calling the script directly.

The entries itself are not being set by me. They must be created by an installer in an earlier installation step.

I don't have a lot experience with setting environment variables and I don't know what and why it is like this.

Does anybody know what's going on?

**Update #1:**

I still don't have a clean solution on this.

Some more details:

I am creating an unattended installation of a software. The first step calls a setup. It seems that the setup routine adds 2 folder paths to **PATH** environment variable.

In the second step I call a batch script which needs those 2 folders paths in **PATH** variable, but it fails because they are not there.

I tried to reload the variables in PowerShell before calling the batch with the line:

```
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
```

It seems to work for the PS environment but there is no change for the batch.
Calling the script a second time it works. It is also working after a reboot.

**Update #2:**

[image: New Environment]

Comment: Can you reproduce issue after reboot?

Comment: What about something like [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794507/reload-the-path-in-powershell)

Comment: @PetSerAl: I did just try it. I can confirm, that it is OK after a reboot.

Comment: @BenH: That sounds suitable. I think I will have to test this with a clean install ...

Comment: To ease comparing I suggest you issue in Powershell `(gci env:path).value.split(";")` and in a cmd window `cmd /D /K @for %A in ("%Path:;=";"%") do @Echo:%~A` the latter will exclude possible `autoruns` which might inject the additional path entries.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I need to get it qorking without reboot.
I tried the tip from @BenH right now. Before calling the Batch-Script I reloaded the Path-Variable as described in the link.
It was not successfull the first time I called it, but it was successfull the second time??? I need to make further testing tomorrow ...

Answer (score 1):

Each process has its own list of environment variables. Every time a process is created, Windows **copies** the current list of environment variables of the running process for the new process into a separate memory area.

No child process can modify the environment variables of its parent process nor can a parent process modify the environment variables of one of its child processes. If that would be possible it would mean that any process could manipulate the working memory of any other process and that would be definitely not good.

The environment variables management can be easily seen on doing following from within a command prompt window:

```
title First CMD
set PATH
```

The first line changes the window title for the command process window to `First CMD`.

The second command lists all environment variables starting with `PATH` and their values. This means usually the environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` with their values as currently in environment variables list of running command process.

```
set "PATH=%PATH%;%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
start "Second CMD"
```

The first line appends your desktop directory to `PATH` of **current** command process. The second line opens one more command prompt window
with window title `Second CMD`. This second command process gets a copy of all environment variables of current command process.

Run in **second** command prompt window:

```
set PATH
```

Output is `PATHEXT` and `PATH` which contains at end your desktop directory. So it can be seen here already that the new command process was created with same environment variables as defined for first command process on starting the second command process and not what is stored in Windows registry and displayed on looking on environment variables in advanced system settings of Windows.

Switch to **first** command prompt window and execute:

```
set PATH=
sort /?
```

The result is the error message:

> sort is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

`sort.exe` in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` is not found anymore by Windows command interpreter in this command process because **local** `PATH` with all the directory paths to search for executables and scripts does not exist anymore **in this command process** except the current directory is by chance `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

Run in **first** command prompt window:

```
start "Third CMD"
```

Run in opened **third** command prompt window:

```
set PATH
```

Listed is only `PATHEXT` with its value. `PATH` was not defined anymore in first command prompt window and therefore does also not exist in third command prompt window.

Run in **third** command prompt window:

```
set PATH=%SystemRoot%\System32
sort /?
```

The help of external command **SORT** is displayed as the executable could be found by Windows command interpreter in third command process because of **local** `PATH` being defined again with the path of the directory containing `sort.exe`.

Switch to **second** command prompt window and run:

```
sort /?
```

The help of external command **SORT** is displayed also in second command prompt window because **local** `PATH` still has all the directory paths as on starting it including your desktop folder at end.

Switch to **first** command prompt window and run:

```
sort /?
```

There is still the error message displayed as in first command prompt window `PATH` is still not defined after deleting it before.

So there are 3 command processes now running with

1. no `PATH` defined at all,
2. `PATH` with additional desktop folder not stored in Windows registry,
3. `PATH` with most likely only `C:\Windows\System32` as only folder path.

You could modify now also `PATH` in **user** or **system** environment variables list in Windows advanced system settings, but that does not change anything on the 3 **local** `PATH` of the 3 already running command processes.

Close now all 3 command process windows not further needed.

Take a look on answer on [What is the reason for 'sort' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) It explains where **system** and **user** `PATH` is stored in Windows registry.

I assume that `setup.exe` running first adds directory paths directly to **system** or **user** `PATH` in Windows registry which become effective only for new processes started from Windows desktop or start menu, but not for any already running process.

So you have to do in the batch file what you have done already in PowerShell script, query the values of both `PATH` directly from Windows registry and set **local** `PATH` for the command process executing currently the batch file.

```
@echo off
rem Get directly from Windows registry the system PATH variable value.
set "SystemPath="
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%N in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%N" == "Path" (
        set "SystemPath=%%P"
        goto GetUserPath
    )
)

rem Get directly from Windows registry the user PATH variable value.
:GetUserPath
set "UserPath="
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%N in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKCU\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%N" == "Path" (
        set "UserPath=%%P"
        goto SetPath
    )
)

rem Concatenate the two PATH values to a single value and expand variables.
rem Delete the two environment variables not further needed.
rem Next replace all two consecutive semicolons by a single semicolon.
rem Last remove semicolon from end of directory list if there is one.

:SetPath
call set "PATH=%SystemPath%;%UserPath%"
set "SystemPath="
set "UserPath="
set "PATH=%PATH:;;=;%"
if "%PATH:~-1%" == ";" set "PATH=%PATH:~0,-1%"
```

The last two commands would not be really necessary as it would be no problem for Windows command interpreter if there are `;;` within directory paths list or the directory paths list ends with `;`.

The above batch code reduced to minimum:

```
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%N in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%N" == "Path" call set "PATH=%%P" & goto GetUserPath
:GetUserPath
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%N in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKCU\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%N" == "Path" call set "PATH=%PATH%;%%P" & goto ProcessSetup
:ProcessSetup
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`

---

**By the way:**

An application of which directory path **must** be added to `PATH` in Windows registry to work at all is poorly coded nowadays.

Adding a directory path to **system** or **user** `PATH` in Windows registry should be done only if the application is designed for being mainly executed  manually from within a command prompt window by the users of the application. In this case adding the directory of the application to **system** or **user** `PATH` in Windows registry is helpful for the users of the application.

But an application mainly used via graphic user interface should add its directory path to other locations in Windows registry. Common is the adding the name of the executable with extension to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

or an application (suite) specific registry key which can be queried by all components of the application (suite).

See also answer on [Where is "START" searching for executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386403/3074564)

Comment: Hi Mofi, thanks - I tried your updated script. The `PATH`-variables have been reloded now. It's not perfect (-> have a look at "Update #2" in my request), but the second install-script did start now. The Install itself still Fails and I currently have no idea why. The second time I call it, its running :-(. Maybe I will have to create a task-sequence with reboot after first tasks. Fu****g piece of software .... grrrr
Because your script was working I will mark it as answer! Thank you for the effort!

Comment: I wrote in my answer that `;;` in `PATH` does not matter for Windows command interpreter, but posted also the code to cleanup `PATH` before further processing. Just copy the last two lines from fully commented batch code below the line `:ProcessSetup` in reduced batch code to replace all occurrences of `;;` by `;` in case of __system__ `PATH` ends with a semicolon although that should not be the case, but many installers update the __system__ `PATH` not 100% correct.

Comment: Your installation problem might be caused by other environment variables which are also added to Windows registry by first `setup.exe` and which are required in local environment on execution of this application. Or the application to run requires a running service which is started automatic on Windows start, but not started immediately after installing. Or the installed application requires that the current working directory is the directory of the application to work properly. It would be also good if you post text as text and not as screen shot from text editor display.