# SqlLocalDB not recognized after installation using powershell command

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

when I run these below commands one after another in a same powershell window , we are getting below error.
And it is working when we run the second command in a new powershell window.

step 1: MsiExec.exe /i SqlLocalDB.msi IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES /qn | Out-Null

step 2: sqlocaldb info

error : sqllocaldb : The term 'sqllocaldb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- sqllocaldb info
- 
- CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (sqllocaldb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Any help would be appreciated to run these command in the same batch :)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gDnS.png)

Comment: The installer will update the `PATH` environment variable, but since environment variables are only read once (on startup) the existing PowerShell instance isn't going to have it. There are [ways to work around that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56562186/4137916), although they're quite complicated, and I'd personally just prefer starting a new PowerShell instance from the old one.

Comment: ...except that starting a new instance will inherit the parent's environment, of course, unless you jump through hoops to avoid that, so never mind that last bit. :P

Comment: If the issue is just that powershell doesn't know where to find `sqllocaldb`, then you can update your step 2 to use the full path for this run: `c:\path\to\sqllocaldb.exe info`

Comment: [Reload the path in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794507) seems relevant.