# Script Headless Install .NET 7 SDK on Windows Server 2022 via PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, powershell, dotnet-tool

**Is it possible to headlessly install the .NET 7 SDK on a fresh instance of Windows Server 2022 via powershell or batch script?**

My goal is to spin up a new Instance and then be able to install and execute a global tool, ie this powershell:

```
> dotnet tool install -g nbgv
> nbgv --version
3.5.13
```

However, if I use the [dotnet install powershell scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website), **I get command not found errors on `dotnet`**:

```
dotnet : The term 'dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

---

So far, I'm using AWS EC2 to create a new Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Base image:

[image]

```cs
private async<string> Task StartWindowsServer(Amazon.EC2.IAmazonEC2 ec2Client)
{
   var response = await _ec2Client.RunInstancesAsync(new RunInstanceRequest{
      InstanceType = InstanceType.C4Large,
      ImageId = "ami-0bde1eb2c18cb2abe", //windows2022BaseUSEast1
      KeyName = ...,
      IamInstanceProfile ...
   });

   return response.Reservation.Instances.First();
}
```

Then, once the instance is provisioned, I am using System Manager to run a powershell script to do the install:

```cs
private async Task InstallDotNetAndThirdPartyTool(
    Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.IAmazonSimpleSystemsManagement ssmClient,
    string instanceId)
{
    var installDotNet7 = 
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#examples
            @"&powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command ""[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; &([scriptblock]::Create((Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing 'https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1'))) -Channel 7.0""" +
            Environment.NewLine +          
            "Restart-Computer";

     await ExecuteRemotePowerShell(ssmClient, instanceId, installDotNet7);

     var installNerdBank = "dotnet tool install -g nbgv";

     await ExecuteRemotePowerShell(ssmClient, instanceId, installNerdBank);

    // scritp errors out - can't find `dotnet`
}

private async Task ExecuteRemotePowerShell(
   Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.IAmazonSimpleSystemsManagement _ssmClient,
   string instanceId,
   string powershellScript)
{
    await _ssmClient.SendCommandAsync(
        new SendCommandRequest
        {
            DocumentName = commandName,
            Targets = new ()
            {
                new Target
                {
                    Key = "InstanceIds",
                    Values = new List<string>{ instanceId }
                }
            },
            Parameters = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
            {
                {
                    "commands",
                    new List<string> { powershellScript }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

#### **ERROR:**

```
dotnet : The term 'dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At C:\ProgramData\Amazon\SSM\InstanceData\i-07f13f9a7dacaf6b0\document\orchestration\c8de6390-d27f-4e78-ad88-cf62e85b07

0d\downloads\ExampleScript-638208821382795610.ps1:18 char:1

+ dotnet tool install `
```

#### Additional things I tried

- I added the `Restart-Computer` into the .NET 7 install script thinking that would refresh things, but didn't solve it.
- Figured there was a path issue, so I tried to manually set the path in the .NET 7 installd script, also did NOT work.:

```
$env:PATH=";C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was missing two pieces:

1. I need to manually set PATH as the .NET Install Script does **not** set environment variables (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script#set-environment-variables)
2. I need to refresh the Path environment variable.

Here is the **final PowerShell Script** I ended up using (*note* the explicit `-InstallDir`):

```
&powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; &([scriptblock]::Create((iwr -UseBasicParsing 'https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1'))) -Channel STS -InstallDir c:\dotnet"

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ROOT","$HOME\.dotnet", "User")

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\dotnet\;$HOME\.dotnet;$HOME\.dotnet\Tools", "User")

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT","1", "Machine")

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_NOLOGO", "true", "Machine")

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE", "true", "Machine")

$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")

dotnet --version
```

And special thanks to [Reload the path in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794507/reload-the-path-in-powershell) for the answer on how to reload Path.